# Fix for iframe calling location.href

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to embed a mapquest direction page such as http://www.mapquest.com/maps?1c=Ann+Arbor&1s=MI&1a=1440+Hubbard+St&1z=48109-2083&1y=US&1l=42.293437&1g=-83.724491&1v=ADDRESS&2c=Ann+Arbor&2s=MI&2a=930+N+University+Ave&2z=48109-1055&2y=US&2l=42.278558&2g=-83.737969&2v=ADDRESS using an iframe. The problem is at least one of their javascripts calls location.href which is causing the script to hang. If I'm not mistaken this is because the page I'm embedding the page on is in a different domain. Are there any ways around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to use their "[embeddable maps](http://www.mapquesthelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/122/~/embedded-maps-frequently-asked-questions)" feature instead of iframing it yourself.

Cross-domain DOMing is a no no, and browser makers work hard to make sure you can't violate the same-source policy. This is a major security concern, so it really can't be done.

When I use the "Link to/Embed" option on the site I get this given back to me:

```
<iframe style="height: 270px; width: 450px;" src="http://www.mapquest.com/embed#b
/maps/m:map:12:42.293449:-83.724489::::::1:1:::::::::
/l::1440+Hubbard+St:Ann+Arbor:MI:48109-2083:US:42.293437:-83.724491:address::1:::
/l::930+N+University+Ave:Ann+Arbor:MI:48109-1055:US:42.278558:-83.737969:address::1:::
/io:1:::::f:en_US:M::/e" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

So it appears they make their own scripts etc that run within the iframe.

**EDIT**

Google maps shows the directions on the embedded map, if that's an option for you: [Google Maps link](http://maps.google.com/maps/empw?url=http:%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%3Ff%3Dd%26source%3Ds_d%26saddr%3D1440%2BHubbard%2BSt%2BAnn%2BArbor,%2BMI%2B48109-2083%26daddr%3D930%2BN%2BUniversity%2BAve%2BAnn%2BArbor,%2BMI%2B48109-1055%26hl%3Den%26geocode%3DFfJWhQIdGXcC-ymlqHiPfK48iDGGiJ_dBoMFCA%253BFQIfhQIdtksC-yn9W_1BQa48iDEYldrUzOvmng%26mra%3Dls%26sll%3D42.305325,-83.669417%26sspn%3D0.11299,0.177326%26ie%3DUTF8%26ll%3D42.286155,-83.72711%26spn%3D0.01745,0.01726%26output%3Dembed&hl=en&gl=us)

Comment: The only problem with this is that it doesn't give the directions which is the main thing I want.

Comment: Is Google maps an option? Check my new link I added

Comment: Yes google maps is and I already have it setup but I figure it's always nice to give people an option. It looks like I'll just have to abandon MapQuest though.